# Terminated due memory issue when fetching CoreData

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am trying to fetch CoreData. I know it is a lot of data and I am already using a different Entity to save data. So basically I only need to read the 'old data'. The problem is that my app crashes when I try to fetch this data, because memory explodes. Does somebody know how to get this data, maybe to only fetch half of it at once?

Comment: fetchLimit   property ?

Comment: how many data you have? can you show the stack trace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know it is a lot of data and I am already using a different Entity to save data.

I don't see the relation between using different entity and memory usage. It should not matter at all (unless you have some weird setup with thousands of relationships), given you follow memory management rules that apply to Core Data.

Basic rules:

- If you perform operations in a loop, make sure to free autorelease pool.
- Once NSManagedObject instances are no longer needed, and their amount takes a toll on memory usage, you can turn them into faults by calling `refreshObject:mergeChanges:` on a context.
- You can also call `reset` on context to invalidate all fetched managed objects (mind, that you are not supposed to use these invalidated objects after calling reset).
- Beware of cyclic references - basically, objects that are tied through relations have these kinds of references and you may need to turn them into fault manually/reset context, or simply discard the managed objects context altogether.

Tips for fetching data:

- If you need to fetch a lot of data and it is possible, use Dictionary Result Type, as Dictionary takes far less memory than managed object instances.
- Apply `fetchLimit` to NSFetchRequest in order to limit the number of objects being fetched. Combine it with `fetchOffset` to obtain "window" of data.
- There is also 'fetchBatchSize' to consider.